# Hashicorp Vault PKI Intermediate request missing private key

Tags: certificate, pki, terraform

I try to set up some PKI structure, but when I request an intermediate CSR from vault, no private key is sent back. Neither in [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) where I try to implement it, nor via the API.

I tried:

1. The API https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/pki/index.html#sample-payload-2

   and get just the CSR:

   ```
   bash
   curl \
       --header "X-Vault-Token: s.123456789abcdef" \
       --request POST \
       --data @example.json \
       http://vault.example.com:8200/v1/pki/intermediate/generate/internal
   ```

   And receive the following JSON:

   ```
   {
     "request_id": "e47966f5-6783-90d6-2d46-71c54ce05749",
     "lease_id": "",
     "renewable": false,
     "lease_duration": 0,
     "data": {
       "csr": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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\n7S2NTf9F8CsS+alg4CEka6p/r+oNGHb1GATkKVjLiek=\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----"
     },
     "wrap_info": null,
     "warnings": null,
     "auth": null
   }
   ```
2. Terraform https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vault/r/pki_secret_backend_intermediate_cert_request.html

   ```
   resource "vault_pki_secret_backend_intermediate_cert_request" "pki_int_request" {
     depends_on = [ "vault_pki_secret_backend_config_ca.pki_root_config" ]

     backend = "${vault_mount.pki_root.path}"

     type = "internal"
     common_name = "example.com"
   }

   resource "local_file" "inter_key" {
       depends_on = [ "vault_pki_secret_backend_intermediate_cert_request.pki_int_request" ]

       content  = "${vault_pki_secret_backend_intermediate_cert_request.pki_int_request.private_key}"
       filename = "${path.module}/certs/int_ca.key"
   }
   ```

Where I just get an empty file.
Obviously I'm missing something and would be glad for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the vaultproject.io example code and response for "Generate Intermediate" conflicts with their own documentation.

Their documentation of the "type" parameter says that you must specify "exported" if you want it to return the private key, and "internal" if you want Vault to forever protect the private key.

Their example API call seems to specify "internal", but their example response looks like what I'd expect for "exported", not "internal".

Comment: That did the trick. Looking at the code was what I obviously missed :-D Many thanks!